# Infinite sums and Hilbert Schmidt operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, number-theory

Let $A(H;H)$ be a bounded operator acting from the Hilbert space $H$ to the Hilbert space $H$ such that the eigenvalues of $A$ for a given set of orthonormal eigenvectors $\{e_{i}\}$ in $H$  are given by the set:$1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3.}...$.

Then by definition $A$ is a [Hilbert Schmidt operators](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hilbert-SchmidtOperator.html) (HS) if and only if  for an orthonormal basis $\{e_{i}\}$ of $H$ we have:

$$\sum_{i}\arrowvert\arrowvert Ae_{i}\arrowvert\arrowvert^2_{H}< \infty$$.

This condition implies that $A$ is HS if

$$\sum1+2+3+...< \infty$$.

This can be argued easily that is a non convergent series. However, one also can argue that the series [converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

My question is :

Is $A$ a HS operator?

If not, is there any theory of operators with this kind of behaviour?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: How do you define eigenvalues if $U\neq H$?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question now.

Comment: @yess isn´t a square missing in line 6 ...$\sum_i ||A e_i||_H^2<\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is no Hilbert Schmidt operator , because $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|A e_i|^2_H=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i=\infty$ using the usual summation. The spectrum $\sigma (A)$ is unbounded, i.e. $A$ is not even compact, but a Hilbert Schmidt operator is understood to be even "better" than compact. It would be very difficult if possible at all to justify the application of Ramanujan summation or similar techniques to argue, that $A$ is "Hilbert Schmidt" in some way.